# Front-End Custom Taxonomy Tag Select

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, front-end, select, posting

The theme I am currently using features a front-end dashboard with posting and post editing, but the pre-existing submission form currently lacks a field to select one or more custom taxonomy tags (taxonomy=ptags).  What I would like to do is add either a required drop-down tag selection box to the existing form containing the available tags, or else require the contributor to choose tags using multiple check box fields.  It would be ideal if the selection box, or check boxes, were able to call/fetch all the custom taxonomy tags created in the back-end administration area, and limit front-end selection to a maximum number of tags (e.g., 3) during the posting process.

So, my questiion is how do I add a custom taxonomy tag selection field to the theme's existing front-end post submission form and make it required?  The existing property form (propertyform) starts around line 925 of the following [front-end submission page html](http://pastebin.com/pqRmhwW2).

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help, or at least point me in the right direction.